# Access local file from AWS Lambda function (.NET Core)

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

I've got a .net core lambda function.

Within the function i've got a folder called Content with a html file in there.

Is there anyway to read that file from the function? If so what is the path?

I've got this:

```
var message = string.Empty;
using (var sr = new StreamReader("/Content/email.html"))
{
  message = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But that gives:

Could not find a part of the path '/Content/email.html'.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you used `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get the directory your function is executed from.

eg:

```
var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var filePath = "/Content/email.html"
var finalPath= Path.Combine(basePath, filePath);
```

Comment: does this work for a Lambda function?

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying, right click the file in your solution explorer, click properties. Make sure to change the "Copy to output directory" to "copy always"